# SELECT FROM WHERE IN compared to SELECT FROM on multiple tables

Tags: sql

I attend a database course at my school. The teacher gave us a simple exercise: consider the following, simple schema:

```
Table Book:
    Column title (primary key)
    Column genre (one of: "romance", "polar", ...)

Table Author:
    Column title (foreign key on Book.title)
    Column name
    Primary key on (title, name)
```

Among the questions was the following one:

> Write the query that returns the authors who have written romance books.

I proposed this answer:

```
select distinct name 
from Author where title in (select title from Book where genre = "romance")
```

However the teacher said it was wrong, and that the correct answer was:

```
select distinct name 
from Book, Author 
where Book.title = Author.title 
  and genre = "romance"
```

When I asked for explanations all I got was a *"if you had paid more attention to the course you would know why"*. Brilliant.

So, why is my answer incorrect? What *exactly* is the difference between these queries? What *exactly* do they do, on the DB engine level?

Comment: Attention editers: this is *not* homework, I am looking for a complete answer, not a hint.

Comment: Wish all homework questions were the same. When are you graduating, you said?

Comment: It's one of those situations where there are lots of answers but one is more correct than the others.  Where in is generally SLOWER than doing a join first then limiting your data.  If you were working with a table having hundreds of thousands of rows, the subselect wouldn't not be as efficient.  To prove it look at the execution plans of both queries.  You'll notice the difference when you can read the execution plan.  Personally I'd take one off from the teacher for teaching non-ansii standard joins.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name she means that this is post-homework, and that she wants a complete answer to a theoretical question that she happened to come across in school

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: the OP does not ask about the assigment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Because I already solved the assignment, and I want an explanation on *why* my answer is wrong. If you look at the `homework` tag description, you'll see it doesn't match my situation.

Comment: @Quassnoi In about two years if everything goes right.

Comment: really: the first query is composed by two queries. the queston was: write the query ...

Comment: @rosco: that is still consider only a single statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, right, but 'considered' is not what it is

Comment: @rosco: I meant the *database* will consider that a single statement. Because technically it **is** a single statement for the DBMS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... yes, i know. but the context of the question, was more simple than your deep, and correct, analysis of the db behaviour. my comment was just related to that 'context'. cheers :)

Comment: Besides dinging the teacher for non-standard joins, I have issues with that schema; it violates normalization practices, after all.  Bonus assignment from the community!  Correct the schema, considering the following - books may have more than one author, books may belong to more than one genre.  Attempt to retain the ability to update the author's name, and the genres, by only updating one row (tip - look into 'surrogate' keys).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> *So, why is my answer incorrect?*

You answer **is** correct.

My guess why the teacher marked it as wrong, that he/she tried to practise the use of joins with that question. But that should have been part of the question if it was intended.

> *What exactly is the difference between these queries*

Technically they are different indeed. A DBMS with a simple query optimizer will retrieve the subselect in a different way than the join from your teacher's answer.

I wouldn't be surprised if a DBMS with good optimizer might actually come up with the same execution plan for both queries.

### Edit

I created some testdata with 50000 books, 50000 authors and 7 different genres to test (smaller numbers don't really make sense as the optimizers tend to simply grab the whole table then). The statement would return 7144 rows.

#### PostgreSQL

The execution plans are nearly identical with some small change in the "join" method.

Here is the plan for the sub-select version: http://explain.depesz.com/s/eov 
Here is the plan for the join version: http://explain.depesz.com/s/aTI

Surprisingly, the join version has a *slightly* higher cost value.

#### Oracle

Both plans are 100% identical:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name   | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |        |  6815 |   399K|       |   273   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE        |        |  6815 |   399K|   464K|   273   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |        |  6815 |   399K|       |   172   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| BOOK   |  6815 |   166K|       |    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| AUTHOR | 50000 |  1708K|       |   103   (1)| 00:00:02 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Looking at the statistics when using `autotrace` there is also no difference whatsoever. I didn't bother to actually create a trace file to analyze it as I don't expect to see a difference there.

Things don't really change if an index on `book.genre` is added. Oracle sticks with the full table scan (even with 100000 rows). Probably because the tables are not very wide and a lot of rows fit on a single page.

PostgreSQL does use the index for both statements but there is still no real difference between the plans.

Comment: `7` genres is way too few for the index to be of use (if they are distributed evenly).

Answer (score 16):

Both queries are valid and return the same.

Your teacher uses quite outdated (though still valid) join syntax, and you are using the construct which is less efficient in some databases (`MySQL`, for instance).

If I were your teacher, I would write the query as this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT name
FROM    books b
JOIN    authors a
ON      a.title = b.title
WHERE   b.genre = 'romance'
```

but still accept both your and your teacher's queries, if the course was not specific to `MySQL` optimization.

Can't it be what the teacher meant when he/she said about paying attention?

**Update:**

On the DB engine level both queries would be optimized to use the same plan, except if the DB engine is `MySQL`.

In `MySQL`, your query would be forced to use `Authors` as a leading table, while for you teacher's query, the optimizer can choose which table to make leading depending on the table statistics.

Comment: In other words:  an explicit join would be preferred. Right?

Comment: @Keyser: from the practical point of view, they are the same, but explicit joins are considered by many more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: I appreciate the clarity of your answer! I'll use your syntax from now on. If I may ask a simple question: where could the syntax I use come from? Since I didn't learn it from my course (see: lack of attention), it must come from somewhere else?

Comment: @Cicada: you are asking me about where do you know about `IN` from? Honestly, I don't know! Probably, you read about it on the internet or saw it in a source code, or whatever!